# Firestore rules saying document get function is wrong

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my new app there are a series of projects with costs in the firestore. Below is the rules I'm using to secure these documents:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /projects/{project} {
            function isSignedIn() {
                return request.auth != null;
            }

            function isAdmin() {
                return isSignedIn() && get(/databases/(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin) == true);
            }

            allow read: if isSignedIn();
            allow create, update, delete: if isAdmin();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to deploy this rule set, I get the following errors:

```
Error: Compilation errors in firestore.rules:
[E] 11:41 - Missing 'match' keyword before path.
[E] 11:51 - Forward slash '/' found where identifier or binding expected.    
[E] 11:52 - mismatched input '(' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}
[E] 11:62 - Missing 'match' keyword before path.
[E] 11:62 - Unexpected '/documents'.
[E] 11:78 - Forward slash '/' found where identifier or binding expected.    
[E] 11:79 - mismatched input '$' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}
[E] 11:98 - token recognition error at: '`'
[E] 23:1 - Unexpected '}'.
```

Basically it doesn't like the `get` line. But I got this right out of the firestore documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth). Does anyone have any ideas why this might not work?

Comment: I think you have extra ")" the one after true in the get line. Make sure also the one after admin, I know its in the docs,  but just check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some small errors:

1. you have two not needed `)`
2. you forgot the `$` before the `database`

try this:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /projects/{project} {
            function isSignedIn() {
                return request.auth != null;
            }

            function isAdmin() {
                return isSignedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
            }

            allow read: if isSignedIn();
            allow create, update, delete: if isAdmin();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know a linter for firebase .rules ?

Comment: No, but the console of firebase rules really help to find problems

Comment: These rules do not give any error and are published successfully.

Comment: Thanks. This is what Firebase support came back with as well.